# add button automatically to row table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have function that fill rows of table from another table

```
     if ( rowData==null)
            return;
        if ($('#' + rowidprefix + rowData["Barcode"]).text() == '') {
            var lastRow = $('<tr  id="' + rowidprefix + rowData["Barcode"] + '"/>').appendTo(table.find('tbody:last'));
            if (rowidprefix == 'rowid')
                lastRow.append($('<td/>').text(++rowNum));
            else
                lastRow.append($('<td/>').text(++rowNum1));
            lastRow.append($('<td/>').text(rowData["Barcode"]));
            lastRow.append($('<td/>').html(rowData["ItemName"]));
            lastRow.append($('<td/>').text(rowData["Discount"]));
           if (cachedRows == null)
                cachedRows = new Array();
            cachedRows.push(rowData);


            return lastRow;
        }
```

I want to make the new row draw this button also which is not exisist in previous table as

```
 $('<td/>').html($("<a title=\"split to more than one product\" href=\"#modalSetDonationsProducts\" data-donation-id='1' data-toggle=\"modal\" class=\"btn btn-green\" name=\"btnSplit\">add</a>")));
```

Comment: Do you want to add button in every row of the table or only one button before the table ends?

Comment: Is my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try to do like below:

```
 var lastRow = $('<tr  id="' + rowidprefix + rowData["Barcode"] + '"><td><a title=\"split to more than one product\" href=\"#modalSetDonationsProducts\" data-donation-id='1' data-toggle=\"modal\" class=\"btn btn-green\" name=\"btnSplit\">add</a></td></tr>').appendTo(table.find('tbody:last'));
```

Comment: Now the rows in the old table is not appeared

Comment: You'r question is not at all clear. It would be better if you create [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Thank you a lot , you put me on the way of the Solution

Comment: If the answer works for you, don't forget to mark as an answer because it might helps other in future.